# php array search function

Tags: php

My array pattern is

```
$arrayError= Array ( 
                        [user_name] => 1 
                        [user_pass] => 1 
                        [email] => 1 
                        [iagree] => 1 
                    )
```

I have to check if email is exist and it's value is 1 in the array

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 10):

```
if(isset($arrayError['email']) && $arrayError['email'] == 1){
     //winning
}
```